# $A_{n\times n}$ be a real matrix, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, $(A-\lambda I)^kv=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A_{n\times n}$ be a real matrix, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, for some nonzero vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ we have $(A-\lambda I)^kv=0$ for some $k$ positive integer. Then could anyone  tell mew which of the following

1. $(A-\lambda I)^{k+r}v=0\forall r\in\mathbb{N}$
2. $(A-\lambda I)^{k-1}v=0$
3. $(A-\lambda I)$ is not injective.
4. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$

I wrote $1$ as correct statement by guess, thank you for helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 is correct because you're multiplying the $0$ vector my further powers of $A-\lambda I$.

2 is incorrect, if we just let $k$ be the smallest positive integer for which $(A-\lambda I)^k v=0$.

3 is correct since if it were injective it would be surjective and invertible as well, which would mean $(A-\lambda I)^k$ would have a trivial null space, a contradiction.

4 is correct since $\lambda$ being an eigenvalue is equivalent to $A-\lambda I$ not being injective.

Comment: you can also add: (3) is correct since $v\ne0,T\equiv(A-\lambda I)^k,Tv=T0$

Answer (score 3):

you were right about 1.

(4) is also true. Proof:
$$
\text{det} \left((A-\lambda I)^k \right)= 0 \Rightarrow \left(\text{det} (A-\lambda I)\right)^k=0 \Rightarrow\left(\text{det} (A-\lambda I)\right)=0$$

(2) May  be true.

(3) I will let you decide based on 4.